# How does TikZ sort intersections?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I used the `sort by` key for intersections to sort along a line, expecting the intersections to be numbered 1 through 5. Why were they numbered 4, 5, 3, 1, 2? Playing around with it, I could not seem to figure out how the order is determined. The code and image follow.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=grid] [xstep=3,ystep=2] (0,0) grid (9,8);
    \draw[->, name path=line] (2,1) -- (7,7);
    \draw[name intersections={of=grid and line, sort by=line, name=i, total=\t}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) node {\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Intersections along line are numbered 4, 5, 3, 1, 2.]

Comment: It is because how grid is drawn (first horizontals then verticals) screwing up the sorting mechanism. Draw from `(1,1)` to `(8,7)`

Comment: @percusse Your comment should be an answer!

Comment: @percusse That is kind of correct, but actually the sorting algorithm was just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in PGF which I have since fixed

> https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/480

With PGF 3.1.5 and newer, the example from your question will produce the correct ordering.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=grid] [xstep=3,ystep=2] (0,0) grid (9,8);
    \draw[->, name path=line] (2,1) -- (7,7);
    \draw[name intersections={of=grid and line, sort by=line, name=i, total=\t}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) node {\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**Mini-Update**: I looked a bit into the `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` file and according to how I understand things now the perhaps simplest option is to draw the line pretending it is a curve. Everything else seems to amount to really improve the intersections library, which is far beyond my capabilities. More specifically, in `pgflibraryintersections.code.tex` it is written that

> Note that the precise time inside of a segment may be unavailable
>   (currently, it is only computed for curveto paths and not necessarily
>   for lineto).

So if you replace the line by a straight curve, that is a line that pretends to be curve, you get the expected ordering 1,2,3,4,5.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=grid] [xstep=3,ystep=2] (9,8) grid (0,0);
    \draw[->, name path=line] (2,1) to[bend left=0] (7,7);
    \draw[name intersections={of=grid and line, sort by=line, name=i, total=\t}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) node {\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Interestingly, the computation time increases noticeably when doing this. Again, not too surprising given the statement

> Note: at the time of this writing, the library has quadratic runtime.
>   Experimentally, it performed well while computing ~12 intersections of
>   two plots, each with 600 samples. It failed when the number of samples
>   exceeded 700.

Comment: Very nice Sherlock! Strange that the term "time" is used.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I guess that this is sort of a standard jargon for the parameter of a curve. (Gauss was also a physicist, unfortunately only the magnetic field carries his name... ;-)

Comment: @marmot Among physicists, indeed it is. There are so many cases in physics where a curve is parametrized by time that we tend to get carried away and call the parameter "time" even when it really isn't.

Answer (score 7):

- Well, I almost thought I have it.
- Not an answer but maybe a start for others.
- I tried to start with the example in the manual and then adapt it to your problem.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417485
% Please don't get started :)
% Needed, otherwise color shift (ASdobe Reader, see for yourself)
\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}

\begin{document}

\section*{Your Code}
% ~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[name path=grid] [xstep=3,ystep=2] (0,0) grid (9,8);
    \draw[->, name path=line] (2,1) -- (7,7);
    \draw[name intersections={of=grid and line, sort by=line, name=i, total=\t}]
        \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(i-\s) node {\s}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\section*{Taken from the Manual}
% ~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-0.5,-0.75) rectangle (3.25,2.25);
\foreach \pathname/\shift in {line/0cm, curve/2cm}{
\tikzset{xshift=\shift}
\draw [->, name path=curve] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0);
\draw [->, name path=line] (0,-.5) -- (1,2) ;
\fill [name intersections={of=line and curve,sort by=\pathname, name=i}]
[red, opacity=0.5, every node/.style={left=.25cm, black, opacity=1}]
\foreach \s in {1,2,3}{(i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Playing Around}
% ~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->, name path = myCurve, blue] (1,1.5) .. controls (-1,1) and (2,0.5) .. (0,0);
\node[anchor = west, blue] at (1,1.5) {Curve Start};
\node[anchor = east,yshift = -2.5mm, blue] at (0,0) {Curve End};
\draw [->, name path = myLine] (0,-.5) -- (1,2) ;
\fill [name intersections = {of = myLine and myCurve, sort by = myCurve, name = myIntersectionIndex}]
[red, opacity = 0.5, every node/.style={left = 2mm, black, opacity=1}]
% ~~~
\foreach \myForEachCounter in {1,2,3}{
    (myIntersectionIndex-\myForEachCounter) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\myForEachCounter}
    };
% ~~~   
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Adressing Your Problem 1/2}
% ~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->, name path = myLine] (1,1) -- (5,5) ;
\draw[name path = myGrid] [xstep = 3, ystep = 2] (0,0) grid (9,8);
\fill [name intersections = {of = myLine and myGrid, sort by = myLine, name = myIntersectionIndex}]
[red, opacity = 0.5, every node/.style={left = 2mm, black, opacity=1}]
% ~~~
\foreach \myForEachCounter in {1,2,3}{
    (myIntersectionIndex-\myForEachCounter) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\myForEachCounter}
    };
% ~~~   
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Adressing Your Problem 2/2}
% ~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->, name path = myLine] (0.5,2.5) -- (9,9) ;
\draw[name path = myGrid] [xstep = 2, ystep = 2] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\fill [name intersections = {of = myLine and myGrid, sort by = myLine, name = myIntersectionIndex}]
[red, opacity = 0.5, every node/.style={left = 2mm, black, opacity=1}]
% ~~~
\foreach \myForEachCounter in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}{
    (myIntersectionIndex-\myForEachCounter) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\myForEachCounter}
    };
% ~~~   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]