# Tikz \path command - use second intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am aiming to produce the following diagram:
[image]

Here's an MWE which *almost* does that:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,matrix,patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \footnotesize

    \draw[<->] (0,15)--(0,0)--(16.5,0); 
    \draw[name path = S] (0,0) ..controls (1,5) and (9,9.5) .. (12,10.1) node[right]{$S$};
    \draw[name path = Y] (0,0)--(12,12) node[right]{$Y$};

    \path [name intersections={of=S and Y, by = I1}];

    \draw[dashed] let \p1 = (I1) in (\x1,0) node[below]{$k^*$} --(\x1,\y1); 

    % a loop to generate the arrows on the x-axis
    \foreach\i in {1,...,5}{
        \draw let \p1 = (I1) in  (\x1,0) node[shift={(0.5*\i,0)}] {$<$};
        \draw let \p1 = (I1) in  (\x1,0) node[shift={(-0.5*\i,0)}] {$>$};
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This MWE produces this output:

[image]

I actually know why it is going wrong. The lines Y and S have two intersections - one at the origin, and one higher up (the one I actually want to work with). My code which specifies the coordinates of `I1` is:

```
\path [name intersections={of=S and Y, by = I1}];
```

and this takes the first intersection at `(0,0)`, which is why the output is as you see.

However, despite knowing the problem, I don't know how to fix it.

> How do I modify that code to get the second intersection instead?

---

There is a 'cheat' which can be used to solve the problem. Simply change the initial coordinates of the Y line from `(0,0)` to `(0.001, 0)`. This removes the first intersection with no visible effects. However, I'd still like to know how to solve it robustly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a list to the `by` key, and then the intersections will get named according to the list. You can even sort the intersections along one path, using the `sort by` key, but this [may fail for complex collections of straight lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644/121799).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,matrix,patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \footnotesize

    \draw[<->] (0,15)--(0,0)--(16.5,0); 
    \draw[name path = S] (0,0) ..controls (1,5) and (9,9.5) .. (12,10.1) node[right]{$S$};
    \draw[name path = Y] (0,0)--(12,12) node[right]{$Y$};

    \path [name intersections={of=S and Y, by ={aux, I1}}];

    \draw[dashed] let \p1 = (I1) in (\x1,0) node[below]{$k^*$} --(\x1,\y1); 

    % a loop to generate the arrows on the x-axis
    \foreach\i in {1,...,5}{
        \draw let \p1 = (I1) in  (\x1,0) node[shift={(0.5*\i,0)}] {$<$};
        \draw let \p1 = (I1) in  (\x1,0) node[shift={(-0.5*\i,0)}] {$>$};
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: instead `\path [name intersections={of=S and Y, by ={aux, I1}}];
 \draw[dashed] let \p1 = (I1) in (\x1,0) node[below]{$k^*$} --(\x1,\y1); ` you can shortly write `\draw[name intersections={of=S and Y, by = {I1,I2}}, dashed]   (I1) -- (I1 |- aux) node[below] {$k^*$};`

Comment: @zarko The reason I didn't do that is because I needed to use the `I2` coordinates in three places.