# The order of intersections between a line and a circle with \tkzInterLC (tkz-euclide)

Tags: tkz-euclide

There may be two points of intersection between a line and a circle. How can we determine the order of the result given by the macro `\tkzInterLC`?

Here is a simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{2/0/A,-2/0/B,0/1/C,0/0/O}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,O)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,O)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](C)
\tkzDrawLine(A,B)
\tkzDrawCircle(O,C)
\tkzInterLC(A,B)(O,C) \tkzGetPoints{P}{Q}
\tkzDrawPoints(P,Q)
\tkzLabelPoints(P,Q)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can we know which of (1,0) and (-1,0) goes to P and which goes to Q?

I think similar situation also exists for `\tkzInterCC`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! If you were willing to use "plain" Ti*k*Z you could use the `sort by` key that comes with the `intersections` library.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Rather than posting code fragments it is better to give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: It seems that O->P->Q are in the clockwise orientation in the diagram. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I could not seem to figure out how the order is determined and I made this package

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: if you were to consider plain Ti*k*Z, then the answer is that you can determine the ordering yourself with the `sort by` key. The plain Ti*k*Z version of your scenario is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (2,0) coordinate (A) (-2,0) coordinate (B)  (0,1) 
coordinate (C) (0,0) coordinate (O);
\node[draw,name path=circ] (Circ) at (O) [circle through={(C)}]{};
\draw[name path=line] (A) -- (B);
\draw[thick,blue,->,name intersections={of=circ and line,sort by=circ}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The arrow is drawn from the first intersection to the second one. This is because the intersections are ordered according to the circle, and the circle path starts at 0 degrees and runs to 360. Thus, if you rotate the line

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-45:2) coordinate (A) (135:2) coordinate (B)  (0,1) 
coordinate (C) (0,0) coordinate (O);
\node[draw,name path=circ] (Circ) at (O) [circle through={(C)}]{};
\draw[name path=line] (A) -- (B);
\draw[thick,blue,->,name intersections={of=circ and line,sort by=circ}] (intersection-1) -- (intersection-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get

[image]

However, if you sort along a straight line, the results [can be unexpected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644/121799), but [you can cure this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418650/121799).