# Labeling distinct points of a line and circle using "intersections package"

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

The following code renders five circles, each circle intersecting one or two other circles, and a line segment `PQ`. Line segment `PQ` intersects each circle twice. How do I label the intersection of the line segment and `circle_1` at `(0,-r)` to be `PQ_1` and the other intersection with `circle_1` to be `PQ_2`?  How do I label the intersection of the line segment and `circle_2` that is "close to `PQ_2`" to be `PQ_3`, and the intersection of the line segment and `circle_3` that is "close to `PQ_3`" to be `PQ_4`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]


\draw[blue, name path=circle_1] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (0,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_2] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (3.40851,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_3] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({2*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_4] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({3*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_5] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({4*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);

\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (P) at (0,-\n1);
\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)}, \n2={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (Q) at ({4*3.40851},\n2);
\draw[name path=PQ] (P) -- (Q);


\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_1, by=PQ_1}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_2, by=PQ_2}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_3, by=PQ_3}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_2, by=PQ_4}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_4, by=PQ_5}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_3, by=PQ_6}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_5, by=PQ_5}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_4, by=PQ_6}];

\draw[fill=green] (PQ_5) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
\draw[blue, name path=circle_1] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (0,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_2] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (3.40851,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_3] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({2*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_4] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({3*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_5] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({4*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);

\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (P) at (0,-\n1);
\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)}, \n2={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (Q) at ({4*3.40851},\n2);
\draw[name path=PQ] (P) -- (Q);

\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_1, by={PQ_1, PQ_2}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_2, by={PQ_3, PQ_5}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_3, by={PQ_7, PQ_4}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_4, by={PQ_8, PQ_6}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_5, by={PQ_10,PQ_9}}];

\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
    \draw (PQ_\i) circle (1pt) node[below,font=\tiny] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you putting the intersections in order for me.

Comment: How would I draw a blue arc from `PQ_1` to `PQ_2` going clockwise, a yellow arc from `PQ_1` to `PQ_2` going counterclockwise, a blue arc from `PQ_3` to `PQ_5` going clockwise, and a yellow arc from `PQ_3` to `PQ_5` going counterclockwise?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I want the circles to be drawn in two colors. The arcs of the circles above line segment `PQ` are to be drawn blue, and the arcs of the circles below `PQ` are to be drawn yellow.

Answer (score 1):

A much shorter and simpler solution than the one below. (Note that I draw the straight line with `to[bend left=0]`. Why? See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418650/121799).)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]
 \draw[blue, name path=circles] foreach \X in {0,...,4} 
   {({\X*3.40851},0) circle [radius={sqrt(18/pi)}]};
 \draw[name path=PQ] (0,{-sqrt(18/pi)}) coordinate (P) 
  to[bend left=0] ({4*3.40851},{sqrt(18/pi)}) coordinate (Q);
 \path[name intersections={of=PQ and circles,sort by=PQ,name=PQ,total=\t}]
 foreach \X in {1,...,\t}
    {node[above] at (PQ-\X) {\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or (using `sort by`)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.25cm, y=0.25cm]


\draw[blue, name path=circle_1] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (0,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_2] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in (3.40851,0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_3] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({2*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_4] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({3*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);
\draw[blue, name path=circle_5] let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in ({4*3.40851},0) circle (\n1);

\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (P) at (0,-\n1);
\path let \n1={sqrt(18/pi)}, \n2={sqrt(18/pi)} in coordinate (Q) at ({4*3.40851},\n2);
\draw[name path=PQ] (P) -- (Q);


\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_1, by=PQ_1}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_2, by=PQ_2}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_3,sort by=circle_3, by={dummy,PQ_3}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_4,sort by=circle_4, by={PQ_5,PQ_4}}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_5,sort by=circle_5, by={PQ_6,PQ_5}}];

\foreach \X in {1,...,6}
{\node[above] at (PQ_\X) {\X};}
\draw[fill=green] (PQ_5) circle (1.5pt);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot  Yes, I think that this is what  I wanted.  I think that I had `by=PQ_5, PQ_4` instead of `by={PQ_5, PQ_4}`.

Comment: @JouleV I agree, see my update. ;-)

Comment: @marmot You did not type your comment fast enough ;)

Comment: @JouleV What do you expect, [hibernation just ended](https://twitter.com/MarmotRecovery/status/1124414651419119616/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Eembeddedtimeline%7Ctwterm%5Eprofile%3AMarmotRecovery%7Ctwgr%5E363937393b636f6e74726f6c&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarmots.org%2Fcategory%2Fnews-from-the-field%2F). ;-)

Comment: How would I draw a blue arc from `PQ_1` to `PQ_2` going clockwise, a yellow arc from `PQ_1` to `PQ_2` going counterclockwise, a blue arc from `PQ_3` to `PQ_5` going clockwise, and a yellow arc from `PQ_3` to `PQ_5` going counterclockwise?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Which version are you talking about? In the first code you may use `\path[name intersections={of=PQ and circles,sort by=PQ,name=PQ,total=\t}]
 \pgfextra{\xdef\NumInt{\t}}
 foreach \X in {1,...,\t}
 {node[above] at (PQ-\X) {\X}};
 \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \NextX using {int(\X+1)}]in {1,...,\numexpr\NumInt-1}
 {
 \ifodd\X
 \draw[blue] (PQ-\X) to[bend left] (PQ-\NextX);
 \else
 \draw[yellow] (PQ-\X) to[bend right] (PQ-\NextX);
 \fi
 }`.

Comment: These commands in your `\foreach` command are not familiar to me. Please give me the commands individually for `circle_1` and `circle_2`.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I still do not know which of the two codes you are referring to.

Comment: Use the following three commands.

Comment: `\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_1, by={PQ_1, PQ_2}}];`

Comment: `\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_2, by={PQ_3, PQ_5}}];`

Comment: `\coordinate[name intersections={of=PQ and circle_3, by={PQ_7, PQ_4}}];`

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire `\draw[red] let
\p1=($(PQ_1)-({0*3.40851},0)$),\p2=($(PQ_3)-({0*3.40851},0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in ($({0*3.40851},0)+(\n1:\n3)$) arc(\n1:\n2:\n3);
\draw[yellow] let
\p1=($(PQ_1)-({0*3.40851},0)$),\p2=($(PQ_3)-({0*3.40851},0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in ($({0*3.40851},0)+(\n1:\n3)$) arc(\n1:\n2-360:\n3);`

Comment: `\draw[red] let
\p1=($(PQ_3)-({1*3.40851},0)$),\p2=($(PQ_5)-({1*3.40851},0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in ($({1*3.40851},0)+(\n1:\n3)$) arc(\n1:\n2:\n3);
\draw[yellow] let
\p1=($(PQ_3)-({1*3.40851},0)$),\p2=($(PQ_5)-({1*3.40851},0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in ($({1*3.40851},0)+(\n1:\n3)$) arc(\n1:\n2-360:\n3);`

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire But this is IMHO a so-called xy problem because what you really seem to be looking for is the `intersection segments` that can be drawn with the `pgfplots` (!) library `fillbetween`.

Comment: What is "atan2(\y1,\x1)"?  I have only used "atan(\y1/\x1)".

Comment: Why is the command ...

Comment: `\path[fill=red!25] let \p1=($(PQ_6)-(3*3.40851,0)$), \p2=($(PQ_8)-(3*3.40851,0)$), \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, \n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}, \n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in ($(3*3.40851,0) +(\n1:\n3)$) arc (\n1:\n2-360:\n3);`

Comment: ... coloring the fourth circle pink instead of only that part of the fourth circle below line segment `PQ`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire `atan2` also puts you in the right quadrant. That is, if `\y1` and `\x1` are both negative, the sign will cancel in the quotient, i.e. in `atan`, but not in `atan2`. Other than that I feel that this post is now at a stage where no one else will benefit any more from the discussion. If you have a clear question others may benefit from too, please ask a new question. I get now some information scattered over several comments and find it impossible to extract the relevant information, so I stop here.

Comment: I get an error if I replace `atan2` with `atan` in this code. I have used `atan` in hundreds of other `TikZ` environments. I will post another question about this code later.