# Sequence of TiKz intersection points

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

To get intersection points of `help lines` and a line, I wrote the following code.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw,help lines,name path=grid] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\path [draw,name path=line] (8mm,4mm) --++ (45:2cm);
\path [name intersections={of=grid and line, by={A,B,C}}];
\draw [fill=blue!50](C)--(A)--(2,1)--cycle;
\filldraw (A)circle (0.75pt)node [below]{A};
\filldraw (B)circle (0.75pt)node [left]{B};
\filldraw (C)circle (0.75pt)node [right]{C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you seen in my code, the sequence of the intersection points are `{A, B, C}`. But the sequence on the output is `{B,A,C}`.
[image]
How do I change the locations of A and B, for expected sequence?

Comment: Use e.g. `bend left=0`, i.e. pretend this is a curve, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418650/121799. Would you agree that this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644/121799 ? E.g. `\path [draw,name path=line] (8mm,4mm) to[bend left=0]++ (45:2cm);
\path [name intersections={of=grid and line,sort by=line, by={A,B,C}}];` works (note also `sort by`.)

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw,help lines,name path=grid] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\path [draw,name path=line] (8mm,4mm) to[bend left=0]++ (45:2cm);
\path [name intersections={of=grid and line,sort by=line, by={A,B,C}}];
\draw [fill=blue!50](C)--(A)--(2,1)--cycle;
\filldraw foreach \X in {A,B,C}
{(\X) circle (0.75pt)node [below]{\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Great solution, thank you @marmot. I agree that my question is duplicate of tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644/121799 (+1). If I did the search with "sort" instead of "sequence", I would see your answer.