# TikZ - Explain the computation of the determinant of a square matrix of dimension 3

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to show the classical trick to calculate the determinant of a square matrix of dimension 3. Here is my very beginning code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|CCC|CC}
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    r & s & t & r & s \\
    x & y & z & x & y
    %
    \CodeAfter
    %
    \tikz\draw[blue] (1-1.south east) -- (3-3.south east) ;
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

Here is the unwanted output.

[image]

I would like the path to be hidden by the text as with the a below, and I  need the line to be longer as in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest possibility would be to add a node that is filled white on the corresponding entry. Works, but only if the page background is white (which it is not already in your screen shots). So we need to avoid drawing the line in certain stretches. There are several possibilities, out of which I focus on clips and intersections.

You can use an [`even odd clip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216). So we first find the boundary path of the entry via `fit`, and then perform an even odd clip with that path and some large rectangle. The size of the blocked out region depends on the `inner sep` of the `fit` node. Everything outside the fit circle and inside the big box will be visible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216
even odd clip/.code={\pgfseteorule}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995  
reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}} 
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|CCC|CC}
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    r & s & t & r & s \\
    x & y & z & x & y
    %
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(1-1),save path=\pathA]{};
     \clip[even odd clip,reuse path=\pathA] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]1-1)
      rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]3-3);
     \draw[semithick,blue,-latex,shorten <=-0.8em,shorten >=-0.8em] 
        (1-1.center) -- (3-3.center); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

One can thus spare out all the entries, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fit}
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76216
even odd clip/.code={\pgfseteorule}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995  
reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}} 
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|CCC|CC}
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    r & s & t & r & s \\
    x & y & z & x & y
    %
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(1-1),save path=\pathA]{};
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(2-2),save path=\pathB]{};
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(3-3),save path=\pathC]{};
     \clip[even odd clip,reuse path=\pathA] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]1-1)
      rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]3-3);
     \clip[even odd clip,reuse path=\pathB] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]1-1)
      rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]3-3);
     \clip[even odd clip,reuse path=\pathC] ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=1cm]1-1)
      rectangle ([xshift=1cm,yshift=-1cm]3-3);
     \draw[semithick,blue,-{Latex[round,length=3.5pt]},shorten <=-0.8em,shorten >=-0.8em] 
        (1-1.center) -- (3-3.center); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, intersections can be used.<sup>1</sup>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,intersections}
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|CCC|CC}
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    r & s & t & r & s \\
    x & y & z & x & y
    %
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(1-1),draw,opacity=0,name path=circ1]{};
     \path (1-1.center) -- (3-3.center) 
        coordinate[pos=-0.2] (start) coordinate[pos=1.2] (end);
     \path[name path=line]  (start) to[bend left=0] (end);
     \draw[semithick,blue,-latex,name intersections={of=line and circ1,total=\t}]
       (start) -- \ifnum\t=2 (intersection-1) (intersection-2) --\fi
        (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to spare out several entries, you can use use loops.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fit,intersections}
\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{|CCC|CC}
    a & b & c & a & b \\
    r & s & t & r & s \\
    x & y & z & x & y
    %
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \X in {1,2,3}{
     \node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(\X-\X),draw,opacity=0,
        name path global=circ\X]{};
     }
     \path (1-1.center) -- (3-3.center) 
        coordinate[pos=-0.2] (start) coordinate[pos=1.2] (end);
     \path[name path=line]  (start) to[bend left=0] (end);
     \draw[semithick,blue,-{Latex[round,length=3.5pt]},
        name intersections={of=line and circ1,name=i1,total=\tA},
        name intersections={of=line and circ2,name=i2,total=\tB},
        name intersections={of=line and circ3,name=i3,total=\tC},
        ]
        (start) -- \ifnum\tA=2
        (i1-1) (i1-2) --\fi
        \ifnum\tB=2
        (i2-1) (i2-2) --\fi
        \ifnum\tC=2
        (i3-1) (i3-2) --\fi
         (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup>If you think that I am crazy because I draw a straight line with `bend=0`: the reason is that otherwise it is harder to sort the intersections: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418650.</sub>

Comment: Thanks "another time". ;-) The problem with you is that the Schrödinger's cat is always alive. :-)

Comment: @projetmbc Are you certain? ;-)

Comment: :-) One last question. Whats is the way to do multiple intersections ? I like the code of your third solution and will like to use `\node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(2-2),draw,opacity=0,name path=circ2]{};` and `\node[inner sep=0.5pt,circle,fit=(3-3),draw,opacity=0,name path=circ3]{};`.

Comment: @projetmbc I added a loop and also fixed a bug. In the first run it did not find intersections since the paths were not yet in their final positions. Now I added `\ifnum\t=2... \fi` type statements to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks. The last comment is wlecome because I was starting to search the reason of this choice. TikZ is great !

Comment: @projetmbc Some of the things are only documented in the source codes. In are occasions the manual is even wrong, but there are continuing efforts of improving it. Some of the users on this site (not me) spend a lot of time and energy in doing this. (The safest way to avoid errors in the manual is to have no manual but I am not sure if I like that strategy. So I fully agree that Ti*k*Z is great, there are attempts to make it accessible to users, and there is a manual. ;-))

Comment: I have a project to write some tutorial to share the solutions that I use but this would be only in french...

Comment: In this (very good) answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `c` instead of `C` in the preambles of  the `{NiceArray}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).